# What are the types that are considered callables in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, functor, type-traits

I am trying to understand the hierarchy of concepts and types of things that can be passed as the first parameter of std::invoke.

Let's consider a type `F` such that there exist at least one combination of `Args` such that `std::is_invokable_v<F, Args...>` is `true`.

**Question [1]:** What are all the types `F` can be?

Here is a tentative list:

- a function such as `std::function_v<F>` is `true`
- a function pointer such that `std::function_v<std::remove_pointer_t<F>>` is `true`
- a function reference such that `std::function_v<std::remove_reference_t<F>>` is `true`
- a reference to a function pointer such that `std::function_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<F>>>` is `true`
- a pointer to member function such that `std::is_member_function_pointer_v<F>` is `true`
- a reference to a pointer to member function such that `std::is_member_function_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<F>>` is `true`
- a pointer to member object such that `std::is_member_object_pointer_v<F>` is `true`
- a reference to pointer to member object such that `std::is_member_object_pointer_v<std::remove_reference_t<F>>` is `true`
- a class such that `std::is_class_v<F>` is `true` and such that `F::operator()` exists
- a reference to a class such that `std::is_class_v<std::remove_reference_t<F>>` is `true` and such that `std::remove_reference_t<F>::operator()` exists
- a union such that `std::is_union_v<F>` is `true` and such that `F::operator()` exists
- a reference to a union such that `std::is_union_v<std::remove_reference_t<F>>` is `true` and such that `std::remove_reference_t<F>::operator()` exists
- a closure type
- a reference to a closure type such that `std::remove_reference_t<F>` is a closure type

Is this list correct? Is there any other viable option?

**Question [2]:** Are closure types only the types of lambda expressions or is there other way in C++ to create something which would be considered as a closure type?

**Question [3]:** The standard sometimes talks about function objects: what in the list of question 1) is considered as a function object?

**Question [4]:** Do the following:

- a closure type
- a class such that `std::is_class_v<F>` is `true` and such that `F::operator()` exists
- a union such that `std::is_union_v<F>` is `true` and such that `F::operator()` exists

belongs to a particular concept in the standard (basically something that has an `operator()`)? If not, what would be a good name (for example if such a thing has a common name in computer science or in other programming languages) for a type trait that would detect if a type satisfies one of the bullet points listed?

Comment: I thought a callable was just "any `x` such that `x(some arguments)` is valid"

Comment: "*a closure type*" This is redundant, since closure types are by definition class types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Function types of the form `R(Args...)`, `R(Args...) noexcept`, `R(Args......)` and `R(Args......) noexcept`.
2. (Possibly cv-qualified) pointers to #1.
3. (Possibly cv-qualified) class types that have at least one public `operator()` member (including inherited);
4. (Possibly cv-qualified) class types that have at least one public non-explicit conversion function to a) reference to #1, b) #2, or c) reference to #2  (including inherited);
5. (Possibly cv-qualified) pointers to member.
6. References to the above.

For #3, #4, and references thereto, there's the extra qualification that the cv-qualification and value category encoded in the type must be compatible with at least one such function.

["Function object types"](https://wg21.link/c++draft/function.objects#1) are object types that can be called using the usual function call syntax, i.e. #2-#4. Pointers to member do not qualify because you can't call them with `()`.

A ["callable type"](https://wg21.link/function.objects#func.def-3) by definition is either "a function object types or a pointer to member", i.e., #2-#5.

Function types and reference types are not object types and are therefore neither function object types nor callable types, but can become one with the application of `std::decay`.

Comment: Are unions considered to be class types even though `std::is_class_v` is `false`?

Comment: Yes. As far as the core language is concerned, both are class types.

Comment: Can you clarify in your answer why 5 is not a function object type? Can you also clarify why 1 and 6 are not callable types?

Comment: Also, even though `functors` are not part of the core language concept, would you agree that 3 (and only 3) corresponds to the traditional concept of a functor (as seen in other programming languages)?

Comment: "a) reference to #1, b) #2, c) reference to #2" is a hilariously awkward thing to read :-) +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a number of variations along the line of

- a class such that `std::is_class_v<F>` is `true` and such that F inherits an  `operator()`

As for closures and lambda's, note that C++ has no magic lambda's. Lambda's are just objects of class type, created via a convenient syntax. `std::bind` will also produce a `Callable` object, and this too can be considered a closure. But "closure" is a label with no exact meaning in C++ and should not be on the list, as noted by Nicol Bolas in the comments.